# How to solve DeploymentException WELD-001408 as local issue?

Tags: java, maven, glassfish, cdi

Google says I have a *famous* error and there are a lot of ideas to solve that issue. However I'm the only developer of our team having this error after months of deploying without problem. Even older versions already running successfully at customers cannot be deployed by my development system anymore. How can this be a local problem? I wiped my maven repository, replaced glassfish with a backup version (known to work), cleaned my local database, installed a new jdk. Nothing is working. Any ideas?

Update: I use the exact same code that has no problems for customers or other team members.

Update: Although I think it's useless, as other developers don't have that issue and it worked for my exact system for months, here is the complete stacktrace:

```
remote failure: Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app : Exception List with 7 exceptions:
Exception 0 :
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies for type [...] with qualifiers [@Default] at injection point [[parameter 4] of [constructor] @Inject public ...]
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:274)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:243)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBean(Validator.java:106)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateRIBean(Validator.java:126)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBeans(Validator.java:345)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateDeployment(Validator.java:330)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.validateBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:366)
        at org.glassfish.weld.WeldDeployer.event(WeldDeployer.java:199)
        at org.glassfish.kernel.event.EventsImpl.send(EventsImpl.java:128)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:313)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:461)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
        at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:389)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:348)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:363)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1085)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:95)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1291)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1259)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:461)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:212)
        at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:179)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$Hk2DispatcherCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:354)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:849)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:746)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1045)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:228)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
        at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Post your **exact** stacktrace so that we can help.

Comment: You seem to have an application problem -- a problem with your code. The stacktrace says that your dependencies haven't been satisfied, so your app won't deploy. Concentrate on fixing your app, not on weld.

Comment: Please read the question precisely. This exact code is productive in use at customers and other developers from my team. This is a local issue on my system!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem in my branch. A second beans.xml crashed the deployment. However I still don't understand why this influenced other branches with source versions, which are known to run without any problem. Maybe some JRebel magic is the reason for that influence.